# How to call a C++ function in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

I need to call a function with a following signature in GDB:

```
std::string demangle(const char* name);
```

How can I call it in GDB?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
(gdb) info function demangle*
std::__cxx11::string demangle[abi:cxx11](char const*);


(gdb) call demangle[abi:cxx11]("d")
A syntax error in expression, near `:cxx11]("d")'.
(gdb) call demangle("d")
No symbol "demangle" in current context.
```

I'm trying with G++ 7.0, GDB 8.0

Comment: use standard c++ syntax for the function: `p demangle("aaa")`

Comment: @Serge `p demangle("d")` `No symbol "demangle" in current context.`

Comment: Does `call 'demangle[abi:cxx11]'("d")` work?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  Yes! Where can I read more about this gdb magic?

Comment: Not sure where or whether it's documented. I read about it on this site, although I now cannot find the question or answer where someone mentioned it. Using single quotes is documented in the manual as a way to prevent interpretation of `.` in expressions like `'f.c'::foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've found is to wrap C++ function (with std::string) into a C function:

```
static std::string tmp_demangle_str;

const char * cdemangle(const char* name) {
    tmp_demangle_str = demangle(name);
    return tmp_demangle_str.c_str();
}
```

This works as expected:

```
(gdb) p cdemangle("d") 
$1 = 0x7ffff7dd6070 <tmp_demangle_str+16> "double"
```