# How to call a std library function (c++) in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, std

I would like to use gdb (using version 12.1) to debug a c++ program (g++ version 11.3). A minimum reproducible example is as follows:

```cpp
// foo.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a = std::stoi("2");
    std::printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

I compile via `g++ -ggdb -o foo foo.cpp` and then run `gdb foo` as follows

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-conda-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from foo...
(gdb) b foo.cpp:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x24bc: file src/foo.cpp, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /path/redacted/foo 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at src/foo.cpp:8
8           std::printf("%d\n", a);
(gdb) p a // just checking the functions worked as expcted
$1 = 2
(gdb) p std::stoi("3")
No symbol "stoi" in namespace "std".
```

Does anyone understand why I cannot call the `std::stoi` function in gdb? I am coming from python so this is quite a strange phenomenon to me.

I also confirmed that running `p 'std::stoi[abi:cxx11]'("3")` does not work [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877788/how-to-call-a-c-function-in-gdb)

I tried to use the `std::stoi` function in gdb, expecting it to work as it does in my code. I got an error from gdb

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that the reason you cannot call `std::stoi` is because it turns out there is no such function in the C++ library. It doesn't exist at all. What's really happening is that C++ header files alias the legendary `stoi()` function from the C library into the `std` namespace. `gdb` is not a C++ compiler, and it doesn't know any of it. You can be rest assured that `gdb` will have to issues, whatsoever, calling `stoi()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: There is no `stoi` in the C standard library. The only places the sequence `stoi` occur in the C standard are as part of `wcstoimax`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that is indeed surprising to learn! I appreciate the clarification. As @JerryCoffin pointed out, though, it seems `stoi` is not actually present

```
(gdb) p stoi("2")
No symbol "stoi" in current context.
```

Is this just outside the capabilities of gdb? In general what can I count on being able to use?

Comment: When I try this, the function is called `std::__cxx11::stoi`, but calling it still doesn't work, because it needs a `std::string` as first argument, and gdb so far doesn't automatically convert a `const char *` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of ABI versioning, gcc aliases `std::stoi` to an implementation in some other namespace. For example, in my installation (gcc 13.2 on Fedora) if I do `nm -C | grep stoi`, I find that it's actually:

```cpp
std::__cxx11::stoi(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long*, int)
```

To call it, you need to specify the full name as implemented: `std::__cxx11::stoi`. In addition, gdb's code to call C and C++ functions doesn't seem to supply default arguments, so you'd need to specify not only the input string, but also the second and third arguments.

That won't get you a whole lot further though. It'll just get you an error message saying: "Too few arguments in function call."

You can get past that by specifying the second and third arguments, something like: `p std::__cxx11::stoi("1", (void *)0, 0)`, but that just gets you a different error message: "Cannot resolve function stoi to any overloaded instance".

I've tried an explicit cast like `(std::string)"1"`, but that just produces an `invalid cast` error instead. Trying to use `std::string("1")` gets yet another error message about a syntax error in the expression, but still doesn't work.

So, that's a partial answer, at best. I've never gotten the call to actually work (but at least if somebody else wants to try, they can start from at least this far along, instead of starting over from the beginning).

Here's a dump of a complete transcript of various attempts, for what little it's worth:

```
(gdb) p std::__cxx11::stoi("1")
Too few arguments in function call.
(gdb) p std::__cxx11::stoi("1", 0, 0)
Invalid cast.
(gdb) p std::__cxx11::stoi("1", (void*)0, 0)
Cannot resolve function stoi to any overloaded instance
(gdb) p std::__cxx11::stoi((std::string)"1", (void *)0, 0)
Invalid cast.
(gdb) p std::__cxx11::stoi(std::string("1"), (void *)0, 0)
A syntax error in expression, near `"1"), (void *)0, 0)'.
```