# Calling a C++ function with std::string argument from gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

On a Raspbian Stretch, with the following versions:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
pi@raspberry:~ $ gdb --version | head -1
GNU gdb (Raspbian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
```

... I am building the following trivial `test.c` program:

```c++
#include <iostream>

// g++ -g test.c -o test.exe

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734783/in-gdb-i-can-call-some-class-functions-but-others-cannot-be-resolved-why/16735613#16735613
std::string& SSS (const char* s)
{
  return *(new std::string(s));
}
// fake_ptr to prevent optimization; see also:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096341/function-pointers-casting-in-c
static const void* fake_ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&SSS);

void print_string(std::string instring) {
  std::cout << "Printing: " << instring << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
  print_string("Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run this in GDB, and try to call the `print_string` function from the command line, I get the typical error:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ gdb --args ./test.exe
...
Reading symbols from ./test.exe...done.

(gdb) p print_string("Hello")
Cannot resolve function print_string to any overloaded instance
```

... which is why I've tried adding the `SSS()` function. However, when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
(gdb) p print_string(SSS("Hello"))
No symbol "SSS" in current context.
```

... which is why I've tried to "prevent optimization" via `fake_ptr` to begin with.

But then, if I try to print `fake_ptr` itself, I get:

```
(gdb) p fake_ptr
$1 = (const void *) 0x10a7c <SSS[abi:cxx11](char const*)>
```

... which tells me that some sort of a symbol pointing to the SSS function is indeed there - but it also includes some "abi:cxx11" stuff there. Unfortunately just trying to use `SSS[abi:cxx11]` verbatim still does not work:

```
(gdb) p SSS[abi:cxx11]
No symbol "SSS" in current context.
```

So, how can I set up this code, so that I can run the equivalent of `p print_string(SSS("Hello"))` on the `gdb` command line, and have the `print_string` function called correctly?

Comment: FYI, your `SSS()` function creates a memory leak. And [casting a function pointer to a `void*` pointer is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645660/) in the C++ standard, though it may "work" and be supported by particular compiler implementations.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau - the memory leak issue is also mentioned in the original SO post where the SSS function was taken from; also I did not intend to use the pointer itself directly for any purpose, it's just there to prevent the compiler to optimize the SSS function away (and it works as such in the given compiler and version)

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the answer in this comment: [How to call a C++ function in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877788/how-to-call-a-c-function-in-gdb#comment82794732_47877788) ; the program is fine, all we need to do is to change the call on the `gdb` command line from `p SSS("Hello")` to `p 'SSS[abi:cxx11]'("Hello")` with single quotes:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ gdb --args ./test.exe
...
(gdb) p SSS
No symbol "SSS" in current context.
(gdb) p 'SSS[abi:cxx11]'("Hello")
You can't do that without a process to debug.

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10b60: file test.c, line 19.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pi/test.exe

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:19
19        print_string("Hello world");
(gdb) p 'SSS[abi:cxx11]'("Hello")
$1 = "Hello"
(gdb) ptype 'SSS[abi:cxx11]'("Hello")
type = class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > [with _CharT = char,
...

(gdb) p print_string('SSS[abi:cxx11]'("Hello"))
Printing: Hello
$2 = void
```